# What is the right way to know the python version used by virtualenv directory?

Tags: python, virtualenv

E.g., I have a environment dir created by `virtualenv`. What is the right way to know the python version used by virtualenv directory?

Comment: `which python` doesnt give version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below commands. Tested and working -

```
$ virtualenv test_proj
$ source test_proj/bin/activate
$ python --version
```

Answer (score 1):

First activate the virtualenv by navigating to virtual_directory>Scripts>Activate. Once its activated you can simply write

```
python --version
```

, or simply

```
python
```

to see which version of python is being used in the virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

activate your virtual-env and use below command

```
$ python --version
```